# Which book explains the story about how Boba Fett escapes his fate?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

What is the title of the book within *Star Wars* Legends that contains the story about how Boba Fett escapes the Sarlacc pit?

Answer (score 29):

Boba Fett was established as having survived The Battle of the Great Pit of Carkoon in [The Dark Empire comics](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Empire), but how he survived is left rather vague, simply saying

> The Sarlacc found me somewhat indigestible.

[image: Fett Lives!]

This was initially published in [Dark Empire issue 5, released in August, 1992](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Empire_5:_Emperor_Reborn).

---

There are a few stories that deal with the actual story of his survival and escape.

The first, and most detailed is [A Barve Like That: The Tale of Boba Fett](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/A_Barve_Like_That:_The_Tale_of_Boba_Fett), which was published as one of the stories in [Tales from Jabba's Palace](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tales_from_Jabba%27s_Palace), published in January 1996. This is the story that focuses on the escape itself.

It is summarized on Wookieepedia as:

> Boba Fett is being eaten by the Sarlaac. During the Battle of the Great Pit of Carkoon, Boba Fett fell victim to the Sarlaac and is now being slowly digested. Susejo a previous victim of the Sarlaac talks to Fett in his head, telling him stories of a Jedi that the Sarlaac had once eaten. But Fett is not interested. Boba Fett focuses on surviving. He focus on becoming the first individual to ever escape from the belly of a Sarlaac.

[image: tales from jabbas palace]

---

The second is the short story [Payback: The Tale of Dengar](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Payback:_The_Tale_of_Dengar) which was published as one of the stories in [Tales of the Bounty Hunters](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tales_of_the_Bounty_Hunters), published in December 1996.

It details Dengar finding Boba Fett having just survived his escape from Sarlacc. This story deals mostly with Dengar nursing Fett back to health, and only relates a little information of the escape itself.

[image: tales of the bounty hunters.]

---

The third is [The Mandalorian Armor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Mandalorian_Armor) published in January 1998, which is a part of [The Bounty Hunter Wars trilogy of books](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Bounty_Hunter_Wars).

The trilogy is summarized as

> The Bounty Hunter Wars trilogy was written by K. W. Jeter. It details the events of Boba Fett, Dengar, Neelah, and Kuat of Kuat starting just days after the battle at Jabba's Palace and Boba Fett's escape from the sarlacc pit. The trilogy makes extensive use of bounty hunter characters from Star Wars Episode V: The Empire Strikes Back and Tales of the Bounty Hunters, including Zuckuss, 4-LOM, Dengar, and Bossk.

The scenes regarding Fett's survival and escape are from the early portions of the *The Mandalorian Armor* book, and is an expanded retelling of the *A Barve Like That* story meshed with the *Payback: The Tale of Dengar* story, mostly as a setup for the rest of the books. If you've read the previous two stories by this point, you've already gotten most of the pertinent information.

[image: The Mandalorian Armor cover]

Comment: This is the correct answer. I'm annoyed I decided to check my e-mail before coming here, because you beat me to it. *The Bounty Hunter Wars* and *Last Man Standing* also mention this, but in passing. *A Barve Like That* is by far the most detailed description of Fett's time in the Sarlacc.

Comment: I'd still recommend adding Bounty Hunter wars to the answer. It explains a lot of details.

Comment: I'd also add *Dark Empire* to this list which, AFAIK, was the one that established he'd survived in the first place.

Comment: @JimmyShelter Does it go over *how* he got out though?

Comment: It's been a long time since I read it, but I remember Fett just being there without no real explanation. Wookieepedia doesn't mention an explanation being mentioned either.

Comment: @phantom42 - I haven't read it in full, but the relevant panel just has Fett saying "the Sarlacc found me somewhat indigestible".

Comment: I recall he got his jetpack working but I've no idea where I heard that, or whether it's just a fan-theory.

Comment: @Richard, Sort of. Fett essentially tricks Sarlacc into igniting his jetpack, which kills it and allows his escape, but leaves Fett extremely injured.

Comment: What I never understood is that C-3PO said "where you will be slowly digested over a thousand years", yet a few days in the Sarlacc was enough to melt Fett's armor and give him burn scars over most of his body. At that rate of acidity, there's no way even bones would last a thousand years.

Answer (score 0):

His survival also appears in the marvel starwars comic, i want to say issue 81 or 82, that came out just after Jedi.  The sarlaac spit him out, and if I remember correctly at the end of the story he's in one of the Jawa Sand Crawlers that go back in, but I would assume that if it couldn't digest him, it couldn't digest an entire ship either.

Answer (score -2):

I remember reading that he used explosives and that the juices from the Sarlacc ate through his armor and disfigured him if you go by the Dark Horse Comics and the [Bounty Hunter Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Bounty_Hunter_Wars)